# How to set V$SESSION.PROGRAM via OCI?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Using the JDBC thin client, it is possible for the client to configure what is displayed in the `PROGRAM` column of the `V$SESSION` view (this is done by setting the [`CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_VSESSION_PROGRAM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_VSESSION_PROGRAM) connection property).

Is there a similar capability for a C program using OCI?

There are ways to set `CLIENT_INFO`, `MODULE` and `ACTION` as well as `V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO.DRIVER_INFO` using the [session handle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnoci/handle-and-descriptor-attributes.html#GUID-FB263210-118E-4DB3-A840-1769EF0CB977), but I could find nothing for `PROGRAM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [here's an archived blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190211161640/http://www.slaviks-blog.com/2009/10/01/oracle-client-changing-the-program-name-in-the-session/) (with example C code) on the topic. The author says you can do it by overwriting `argv[0]` early in your program, and OCI will send that program name to the server, e.g.

```
prglen = strlen(argv[0]);
strncpy(argv[0], "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", prglen);
```

Comment: This is a possibility, but that would also change the `ps` output for the process, which is not desirable. I guess I could do that right before I connect to Oracle and then restore the original name.

Comment: Bump. Has anybody come up with a cleaner solution for this?